# DoctrineEncryptBundle Symfony - encrypted field updated although the entity is only selected

Tags: symfony, encryption, doctrine-orm

On Symfony4, I'm using Ambta\DoctrineEncryptBundle to encrypt some columns in my DB.

Functionnaly, everything works fine but logs show that when the entity is selected, if there is a flush somewhere, then the entity is updated with new values in the encrypted columns (the plain data is unchanged, so it's just a performance issue : it should not update something that is not changed).

Here is an example of a function that does nothing but querying the entity User (housing auth data) that is linked to the entity Identity (housing name/givenname of the User).

```
    /**
    * @Route("/myaccount2/", name="myAccount2", methods={"GET", "POST"})
    * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
    */
    public function myAccount2(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $logger->debug('before');
        $em->flush();
        $logger->debug('after');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }
```

This should do nothing on the DB, but logs show this :

```
[2020-05-07 09:42:14] app.DEBUG: before [] []
[2020-05-07 09:42:14] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2020-05-07 09:42:14] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE identity SET name = ?, given_name = ? WHERE id = ? ["MUIEAAYnaoFEu3KQ1Y-HH6XfRb [...]","MUIEADmhmrmQJgV-ITjZymLS-- [...]","a8c39458-8213-4534-9767-57 [...]"] []
[2020-05-07 09:42:14] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
[2020-05-07 09:42:14] app.DEBUG: after [] []
```

And a look at the DB shows that the corresponding values are actually updated.

Here are parts of the definition of the involved entities :

**User**

```
    /**
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
    * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="security.alreadyused")
    */
    class User implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
        * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Identity", mappedBy="User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
        */
        private $identity;
```

**Identity**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use Ambta\DoctrineEncryptBundle\Configuration\Encrypted;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\IdentityRepository")
     * @UniqueEntity(
     *     fields={"alias"},
     *     message="public.alias.unique"
     * ))
     */
    class Identity
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=36, nullable=false)
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1000)
         * @Encrypted
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1000)
         * @Encrypted
         */
        private $givenName;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="identity", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
         */
        private $User;
```

Note that if the @encrypted is removed from the two fields (name and givenName) in the entity Identity, no update is done on the DB :

```
[2020-05-07 11:06:18] app.DEBUG: before [] []
[2020-05-07 11:06:18] app.DEBUG: after [] []
```

Thanks for any insight on this weird behavior !

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is induced by encryption. When doctrine loads the entity, the data is decrypted.

Two possibilities:

- The decryption action is detected by doctrine when a change and schedule this entity do update.
- In flush action, the new encrypted data is not the same as the loaded data, and the data is updated in the database.

The library Ambta\DoctrineEncryptBundle needs to detect the change and change the encrypted value only on this case.